# What is the result type of operation between integer literals?

Tags: c, integer-promotion

```c
int main(){
 char a = 5 + (16711935 * 1200);
 return 0;
}
```

Based on the [type of integer literals](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/integer_constant) and [conversion rules](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion) in C, `16711935` is of type int and `1200` is promoted to an int. My question is what is the type of the intermediate result of this multiplcation before it gets added to 5 and then converted to a char?

Does the intermediate result also follow the integer literal rules?

Edit:
This question is not specific to multiplication, it is just an example.

Comment: Note C does not call 16711935 an _integer literal_, but an _integer constant_.  C has 2 literals: _string_ and _compound_.   `(int){16711935}` is an _compound literal_ of type `int`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The conversion rules apply to *all* operations involving integer types, whether the operands are integer constants or objects of integer type.

In the case of this expression, the integer constants `5`, `16711935`, and `1200` all have type `int` (assuming an `int` is 32 bits wide), so there is no conversion applied to the operands of the `+` and `=` operators.  The resulting expression has type `int` and is converted to `char` before being assigned to `a`.

The types applied to integer constants are specified on [this page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/integer_constant), which originates from section 6.4.4.1 of the [C standard](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf).

Comment: what if the intermediate result is bigger than an int? say 16711935 * 16711935

Comment: `16711935 * 1671193` is signed integer overflow - UB.

Comment: @Dan Then you have integer overflow resulting in undefined behavior.  The type of the result is dependent solely on the types of the operands, not their values.

Comment: another example then `if (16711935 * 1671193 > 1){}`, what is the result type of `16711935 * 1671193` here?

Comment: @Dan Again, the type of the result is dependent solely on the types of the operands.  So the result of `int * int` is always `int`.

Comment: ok that's what I've been looking for, so there is a rule that says`the result is dependent solely on the types of the operands. So the result of int * int is always int` ? do you have a link to the specific rule?

Comment: @Dan From section 6.3.1.8p1 regarding Usual Arithmetic Conversions: *"Many operators that expect operands of arithmetic type cause conversions and yield result
types in a similar way. The purpose is to determine a common real type for the operands
and result. For the specified operands, each operand is converted, without change of type
domain, to a type whose corresponding real type is the common real type. **Unless
explicitly stated otherwise, the common real type is also the corresponding real type of
the result**"*

Comment: @dbush just wanted to confirm that in `uint64_t a = 16711935 * 1671193;` the result is a `unint64_t`, but in `if (16711935 * 1671193 < 5){}` the intermediate result type of the multiplication is also an `int` (same type as the biggest operand according to conversion rules)  which overflows and we get UB?

Comment: @Dan The result of the multiplication is still an `int`, and that result is converted to a `uint64_t` before assignment.

Comment: @dbush so if the intermittent results still is an int then we also have UB in the first case?

Comment: @Dan Correct.  `int * int` will always result in an `int`, regardless of what other expression it may be a part of.

Comment: Solution is to cast at least one of the inputs to the expected result type then? I.e `uint64_t a = (uint64-t)16711935 * 1671193;`

Comment: @Dan Correct...

Comment: Thank you, could I bother you with one last question? Multiplication is a widening operation, meaning int32 x int32 will result in an int64, however, doing a `uint32_t a = 5 * 6` does not cause an  overflow or UB because even though the result is 64 bits, the higher 32 bits are 0 in this case which does not cause an overflow correct ?

Comment: @Dan No, int32 x int32 results in a int32, so the result can overflow.

Comment: Not talking about C rules here, arithmetically int32 x int32 results in twice it's size, which is int64. It can be even done by hand on paper.

Comment: I will ask this question in a separate post, thanks.